# Django: ImproperlyConfigured The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty when executing gunicorn

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, settings, production

I'm trying to deploy a django application on AWS. I've read all the existing posts regarding the same issue and include the

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tango_with_django.settings")
```

in manage.py and wsgi.py but still it does not work.

My project structure is the following one:

```
--chimpy
    -botApp
       -settings
             -base.py
             -production.py
       -wsgi.py
    -manage.py
```

These are my files:

-base.py:

```
"""
Django settings for botApp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'whatever'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../locale'),
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'profiles',
    'portfolios',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'botApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries':{
            'proper_paginate': 'portfolios.proper_paginate',
            'url_replace': 'portfolios.url_replace',
            }
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'botApp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'whatever',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}






# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../../static"), '/Users/ibotics/suribit/static', ]
STATIC_ROOT = "/Users/ibotics/suribit/static_cdn"

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/templates/',)

LOGIN_URL = '/login'
# media config missing
# static cdn missing?

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8080','localhost:8000',
)
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8080','localhost:8000',
)
```

-production.py:

```
from .base import *
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

-wsgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "botApp.settings.production")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

-manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "botApp.settings.production")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

As you can see all files point to the settings/production.py file, which imports everything from base.py and I have the secret key in there, but still receive the same error Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty when I try to do:

```
gunicorn botApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Does your `settings` directory contain an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Your directory tree suggests that `wsgi.py` is in the `settings` directory. Is that really the case?

Comment: @Alasdair yes, it is empty. I realized wsgi.py is outside of the settings directory, I'll edit the op.

Comment: I can't see the issue from the code you've posted. The full traceback might show what the problem is.